# Linear map and linear subspace exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let be $V=\{ \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^4 | x+y+z+t=0 \}$ and $W=span(1,2,3,4)^T$ two linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

$E=\{ f \in End(\mathbb{R}^4)  | f(V) \subseteq W\}$ is a linear subspace of $End(\mathbb{R}^4)$ ? What is its dimension?

And $E'=\{ f \in End(\mathbb{R}^4)  | f(V) = W\}$ is a linear subspace of $End(\mathbb{R}^4)$ ?

MY IDEA

$V=span\{(1,0,0,-1),(0,1,0,-1),(0,0,1,-1)\}$ so to find the representative matrix of $f$ I need to find a matrix $M$ 4x4 such that:

$M[(1,0,0,-1)] \in (1,2,3,4)$

$M[(0,1,0,-1)] \in (1,2,3,4)$

$M[(0,0,1,-1)] \in (1,2,3,4)$ But how to find it?
(Thanks to $M$ I can find the dimension of $E$)

Answer (score 3):

The dimension of $V$ is $3$ and the dimension of $W$ is $1$ and this is all you need to know.

Extend a basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ of $V$ to a basis $\mathscr{B}=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and a basis $\{w_1\}$ of $W$ to a basis $\mathscr{C}=\{w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

A linear map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ will belong to $E$ if and only if its matrix with respect to $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{C}$ is of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & p \\
0 & 0 & 0 & q \\
0 & 0 & 0 & r \\
0 & 0 & 0 & s
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This is because $f(v_1)$, $f(v_2)$ and $f(v_3)$ are required to be scalar multiples of $w_1$, while $f(v_4)$ can be any linear combination of $\mathscr{C}$.

Can you now tell the dimension of $E$?

For the other question, does the zero endomorphism belong to $E'$?

Comment: I have that $dim(End(\mathbb{R}^4))=16$ and the rank of that matrix is 4, so $dim E=16-4=12$?

Comment: @Besh00 No; how many free variables do you have? The rank of that matrix is not relevant.

Comment: I have 3 free variables

Comment: @Besh00 $a,b,c,p,q,r,s$

Comment: Ok, so the dimension of E is 7

Comment: @Besh00 Yes, it's the subspace of $M_4(\mathbb{R})$ ($4\times 4$ matrices) having nine $0$ entries.

Comment: For the other questions, $f=0$ belongs to $E'$

Comment: @Besh00 Not at all.

Comment: Following the same argument, I would have 5 free variables?

Comment: @Besh00 The zero endomorphism cannot satisfy $f(V)=W$, so $E'$ is ***not*** a subspace.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Many thanks, you opened up me a new world, sorry for my lack of knowledge. Do you know where can I find similar exercises?